# Oracle RDBMS: how to get deleted row number in after delete trigger?

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, rownum

Good day.

I need to get rownum of deleted row in after trigger. I try to use `:old.rownum`, but it doesn't exists in trigger. How i can get it here?

```
create or replace trigger my_trig
  after delete on T1
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(:old.rownum);
end;
/
```

Comment: Did you mean `ROWID` rather than `ROWNUM`?

Comment: @BobJarvis no, i need to get number of deleted row, is it can be implemented in trigger?

Comment: Sorry, but ROWNUM is a pseudo-column which is only available in the rowset returned by a SELECT statement. There is no ROWNUM associated with a DELETE statement because no rowset is returned by a DELETE.

Comment: @BobJarvis thank you for answer! So, i currently understand that here is no way to get number of deleted row in after delete trigger?

Comment: That is correct. There is no sequential number available to tell you that a particular row is the first, or the tenth, or the two-thousand-forty-seventh row deleted by a particular statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROWNUM` is a pseudo-column which is only available in a rowset returned by a SELECT statement. There is no ROWNUM associated with a DELETE statement because no rowset is returned by a DELETE. There is no sequential number available to a DELETE trigger which would indicate that a particular row is the first, or the tenth, or the two-thousand-forty-seventh row deleted by a particular statement.